# How to improve audio performance on high end gaming pc?

Tags: audio-hardware

I have a nice pc, with very good processor and gpu, ssd, 16gb of ram and all that good stuff needed for gaming. But when I made my pc I was focused on video performance, totally forgetting about audio.
Now I'm equipped with cheap Amazon KLIM Mantis USB headphones and the "sound card" built in in my AsRock 450m mobo, but when I'm playing a game like battlefield 5 I'm not quite satisfied with the audio immersion. It sounds pretty flat, although I installed all the drivers and tweaked all settings. 
How should I proceed to improve my gaming audio experience? What to buy first? Better headphones? A cheap dedicated audio card? I'm totally ignorant about audio, please enlighten me

Comment: This seems like a really broad question, and I'm not sure it's answerable because no one knows exactly how your machine is set up except you.

Comment: Doesn't look that broad to me... you know the headset and you know the board, so you have all the information you need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a problem unique to gaming.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a good headset first and then *maybe* another sound card depending on your needs. Nowadays onboard sound cards are usually better than cheap dedicated ones, so you should be fine with just a headset.

Even the best sound cards can't do anything about a shitty headset. It's pretty much like having a Porsche on a cobbled road: it works, but it's no fun at all.

Answer (score 1):

Bottlenecks in terms of audio quality are almost always due to the speakers themselves. Investing in a pair of good noise cancelling headphones can drastically improve your audio quality in games.